# How to make custom CoordinatorLayout.Behavior with parallax scrolling effect for google MapView?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport, android-coordinatorlayout

I try to make a parallax scrolling effect for google `MapView` and `RecycleView` using `CoordinatorLayour`.

so base on some tutorials found on web I made below code.

The layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView android:id="@+id/map_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:layout_behavior="net.lunavulpo.coordinatorlayouttest.MapViewBehavior"
        />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and I made my implementation of `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior`:

```
    public class MapViewBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<MapView> {

        public MapViewBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, MapView child, View dependency) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, MapView child, View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, MapView child, View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed) {

            //child.setTranslationY(child.getTranslationY() - dyConsumed);
            child.setBottom(child.getBottom() - dyConsumed);
//what should I make here?

        }


    @Override
    public boolean onNestedFling(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, MapView child, View target, float velocityX, float velocityY, boolean consumed) {
//what should be here?
        return super.onNestedFling(coordinatorLayout, child, target, velocityX, velocityY, consumed);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNestedPreFling(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, MapView child, View target, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

//what should be here?
return super.onNestedPreFling(coordinatorLayout, child, target, velocityX, velocityY);
    }
    }
```

How to correct implement the parallax scrolling effect?
Maybe there is a library with ready to use Behaviors?
or I miss something and there is a simplest way?

**I don't want to use Toolbar for this at all.**

Comment: Just look at the `Behaviors` defined by the `AppBarLayout` or `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. The easiest solution would probably be to use a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with a `Toolbar` and just style it in a way which hides the fact that it is a `Toolbar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**
I'm going to give you an overview how to do it (I can't post all the answer because I posted it in another question with MORE requeriments than question and my old answer got marked as duplicated...)any way this is how you do it:

**For custom CoordinatorLayout**:
Because you can't extend BottomSheetBehavior, you have 2 options: trying doing your own Behavior or like I did, just copy paste the code from original BottomSheetBehavior and modifying it to get another state (when google maps open a bottomsheet it stop in the middle of the screen, this is the state that I'm talking about).

[here the CustomBottomSheet with the behavior I was talking above](https://github.com/miguelhincapie/CustomBottomSheetBehavior/blob/master/app/src/main/java/co/com/parsoniisolutions/custombottomsheetbehavior/BottomSheetBehaviorGoogleMapsLike.java)

**Now for Image parallax effect**:
I tried all default parallax effect in XML avoiding a Custom behavior but in the end I ended doing one, its not hard, you need to override 2 methods like this:

```
public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency) {
    return dependency instanceof NestedScrollView;
}

public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child,
                                      View dependency) {

    if (mYmultiplier == 0) {
        initValues(child, dependency);
        return true;
    }

    float dVerticalScroll = dependency.getY() - mPreviousY;
    mPreviousY = dependency.getY();

    //going up
    if (dVerticalScroll <= 0 && child.getY() <= 0) {
        child.setY(0);
        return true;
    }

    //going down
    if (dVerticalScroll >= 0 && dependency.getY() <= mImageHeight)
        return false;

    child.setY( (int)(child.getY() + (dVerticalScroll * mYmultiplier) ) );

    return true;
}
```

[Here the link to image parallax behavior](https://github.com/miguelhincapie/CustomBottomSheetBehavior/blob/master/app/src/main/java/co/com/parsoniisolutions/custombottomsheetbehavior/BackdropBottomSheetBehavior.java)

**And here is how its looks like:** 
[[image: CustomBottomSheetBehavior]]

[A link to the project](https://github.com/miguelhincapie/CustomBottomSheetBehavior)
I must clarify that the previous link has FAB and toolbars animations but if you only want bottom and image behavior just ignore the others java files (clarifying because I have to "adjust to the question")

Answer (score 2):

As @Xaver Kapeller suggested, the most painless way to achieve the parallax is to wrap it in `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with collapsing mode `PARALLAX`and parallax multiplier of your choice.

However, if you plan to go with your own behavior, you need to write the implementation in the `onPreNestedScroll()` method.

First, you only care about vertical scrolling. In `onStartNestedScrolling()` you check wither `nestedScrollAxes` is vertical.

Then you accumulate all the `dy` scrolled and translate the dummy view (that works as header) and `MapView`. Reset the `mTotalDy` to `0` when there is a change in the direction of scrolling.

Then for the same negative `mTotalDy` value translate the `ViewCompat.setTranslationY(mDummyView, -mTotalDy)`. To achieve proper parallax, the parallax should translate slower than the dummy view, which means that the `mTotalDy` value should be at least half the speed of translation speed of the dummy view, i.e: `ViewCompat.setTranslationY(mMapView, -mTotalDy/2)`. Therefore you will see it translating up/down slower.

View hierarchy should be: Make sure your z-order is preserved as I described

```
-CordinatorLayout
  -FrameLayout
    -MapView
    -DummyView (same height as MapView, different z-order)
    -NestedScrollView (same z-order as DummyView)
```

You should handle in the same manner when there is nested flinging, hint: use `target.getScrollY()`, where the target is the view that scrolls.

Comment: Can you provide more details for the fling action please?