# Android Bottom Sheet smooth expanding, like Google Maps

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I want to recreate Bottom Sheet Behavior provided in the Google Maps app:

[Link to expected behavior.](https://media.giphy.com/media/1syNHM25tZ1Sw/giphy.gif)

I have tried using [BottomSheetBehavior](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior.html) and couple of other 3rd party libs like umano AndroidSlidingUpPanel but the problem I was unable to avoid is they are all snapping the Bottom Sheet in between states (collapsed and expanded).

I would like to have a Bottom Sheet which can be smoothly expanded by sliding up, without it snapping to the closest state but instead to remain where the user stopped with the sliding.

Comment: Did you find a solution for that? I'm also interested. Thank

Comment: @dor506 nope :| will play around a bit more with this when I find some free time :D

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Probably this post can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33945085/how-to-make-custom-coordinatorlayout-behavior-with-parallax-scrolling-effect-for

Comment: Why not using map in the `CollapseToolBar` ? It can provide smooth scrolling.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by subclassing `BottomSheetBehavior`, and overriding `onTouchEvent` to return early on `ACTION_UP` and `ACTION_CANCEL`.

```
public class CustomBottomSheetBehavior<V extends View> extends BottomSheetBehavior<V> {

    public CustomBottomSheetBehavior() {
        super();
    }

    public CustomBottomSheetBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(CoordinatorLayout parent, V child, MotionEvent event) {

        int action = event.getActionMasked();
        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                return true;
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(parent, child, event);
    }
}
```

This prevents the `BottomSheetBehavior` class from handling these events and triggering the 'expand' or 'collapse' call.

To apply your `CustomBottomSheetBehavior` in xml:
`app:layout_behavior="com.yourpackage.CustomBottomSheetBehavior"`

---

To restore default functionality to the `BottomSheetBehavior` when the sheet is fully expanded or collapsed, you can add a flag which is set when the slide offset reaches a certain value. In the following example, the bottom sheet `ACTION_UP` and `ACTION_CANCEL` events are only ignored when the slide offset is between 0.1 and 0.9.

```
public class CustomBottomSheetBehavior<V extends View> extends BottomSheetBehavior<V> {

    private boolean isExpandedOrCollapsed;

    public CustomBottomSheetBehavior() {
        super();

        listenForSlideEvents();
    }

    public CustomBottomSheetBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        listenForSlideEvents();
    }

    void listenForSlideEvents() {
        setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
                isExpandedOrCollapsed = slideOffset < 0.1f || slideOffset > 0.9f;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(CoordinatorLayout parent, V child, MotionEvent event) {

        if (!isExpandedOrCollapsed) {
            int action = event.getActionMasked();
            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    return true;
            }
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(parent, child, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I cannot scroll in the list I pull up.