# Android - How to add parallax effect as bottom sheet covers another view

Tags: android, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport

Using `BottomSheetBehavior` from the google design library, it looks like the default behavior is for the bottom sheet to "cover" other views in the same `CoordinatorLayout` as it expands.  I can anchor something like a FAB (or other view with an appropriately defined `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior`) to the top of the sheet and have it slide up as the sheet expands, which is nice, but what I want is to have a view "collapse" as the bottom sheet expands, showing a parallax effect.

This effect in Google Maps is similar to what I'm looking for; it starts as a parallax effect, and then switches back to just having the bottom sheet "cover" the map once a certain scroll position is reached:

[image]

One thing I tried (though I suspected from the start it wouldn't work), was setting the upper view's height programmatically in the `onSlide` call of my `BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback`.  This was somewhat successful, but the movement wasn't nearly as smooth as in Google Maps.

If anyone has an idea how the effect is accomplished I would appreciate it a lot!

Comment: Some [libraries](https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui) which can help.

Answer (score 14):

After a bit more experimenting/research I realized from this post
[How to make custom CoordinatorLayout.Behavior with parallax scrolling effect for google MapView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33945085/how-to-make-custom-coordinatorlayout-behavior-with-parallax-scrolling-effect-for) that a big part of my problem was not understanding the parallax effect, which translates views rather than shrinking them.  Once I realized that, it was trivial to create a custom behavior that would apply the parallax to my main view when the bottom sheet expanded:

```
public class CollapseBehavior<V extends ViewGroup> extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<V>{


  public CollapseBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, V child, View dependency) {
    if (isBottomSheet(dependency)) {
        BottomSheetBehavior behavior = ((BottomSheetBehavior) ((CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) dependency.getLayoutParams()).getBehavior());

        int peekHeight = behavior.getPeekHeight();
        // The default peek height is -1, which 
        // gets resolved to a 16:9 ratio with the parent
        final int actualPeek = peekHeight >= 0 ? peekHeight : (int) (((parent.getHeight() * 1.0) / (16.0)) * 9.0);
        if (dependency.getTop() >= actualPeek) {
            // Only perform translations when the 
            // view is between "hidden" and "collapsed" states
            final int dy = dependency.getTop() - parent.getHeight();
            ViewCompat.setTranslationY(child, dy/2);
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
  }

  private static boolean isBottomSheet(@NonNull View view) {
    final ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = view.getLayoutParams();
    if (lp instanceof CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) {
        return ((CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) lp)
                .getBehavior() instanceof BottomSheetBehavior;
    }
    return false;
  }


}
```

Then in my layout XML, I set the `app:layout_behavior` of my main view to be `com.mypackage.CollapseBehavior` and the `app:layout_anchor` to be my bottom sheet view so that the `onDependentViewChanged` callback would trigger.  This effect was much smoother than trying to resize the view.  I suspect returning to my initial strategy of using a `BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback` would also work similarly to this solution.

Edit: per request, the relevant XML is below. I add a `MapFragment` into `@+id/map_container` at runtime, though this should also work with anything you drop into that container like a static image.  The `LocationListFragment` could likewise be replaced with any view or fragment, so long as it still has the `BottomSheetBehavior`

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_coordinator">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/map_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/list_container"
            app:layout_behavior="com.mypackage.behavior.CollapseBehavior"/>

        <fragment
            android:name="com.mypackage.fragment.LocationListFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/list_container"
            app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"/>


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I know this was a while ago, but do you mind posting your xml for this one too?

Comment: No probelm! I've added it

Comment: Thank's for this post, It's helpful. but I have facing an issue, when I expend bottom sheet then logo of google is hiding can we resolve it?

Comment: @RashpalSingh I'm not entirely sure, but if you are using maps sdk v2 or later then this may be achievable using `GoogleMap.setPadding()`, which will move the logo and other parts of the map view without moving the map itself (see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923472/relocate-google-logo-in-mapview). This will require a lot of changes to my code above, since you'll need a way to trigger the padding change from `onDependentViewChanged`, but increasing the padding as the bottom sheet expands should keep the logo visible

Answer (score 4):

Patrick Grayson's post was very helpful. In my case though, I did need something that resized the map. I adopted the solution above to resize instead of translate. Perhaps others may be looking for a similar solution.

```
public class CollapseBehavior<V extends ViewGroup> extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<V> {

private int pixels = NO_RESIZE_BUFFER; // default value, in case getting a value from resources, bites the dust.

private static final int NO_RESIZE_BUFFER = 200; //The amount of dp to not have the bottom sheet ever push away.

public CollapseBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
    pixels = (int)convertDpToPixel(NO_RESIZE_BUFFER,context);
}

@Override
public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, V child, View dependency) {
    // child is the map
    // dependency is the bottomSheet
    if(isBottomSheet(dependency))
    {
        BottomSheetBehavior behavior = ((BottomSheetBehavior) ((CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)dependency.getLayoutParams()).getBehavior());

        int peekHeight;
        if (behavior != null) {
            peekHeight = behavior.getPeekHeight();
        }
        else
            return true;

        if(peekHeight > 0) { // Dodge the case where the sheet is hidden.

            if (dependency.getTop() >= peekHeight) { // Otherwise we'd completely overlap the map

                if(dependency.getTop() >= pixels) { // On resize when we have more than our NO_RESIZE_BUFFER of dp left.
                    if(dependency.getTop() > 0) { // Don't want to map to be gone completely.
                        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
                        params.height = dependency.getTop();
                        child.setLayoutParams(params);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private static float convertDpToPixel(float dp, Context context)
{
    float densityDpi = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
    return dp * (densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
}

private static boolean isBottomSheet(@NonNull View view)
{
    final ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = view.getLayoutParams();
    if(lp instanceof CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)
    {
        return ((CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) lp).getBehavior() instanceof BottomSheetBehavior;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

And the layout...

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/flMap"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/persistentBottomSheet"
    app:layout_behavior="com.yoursite.yourapp.CollapseBehavior">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapDirectionSummary"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.yoursite.yourapp.YourActivity" />

</FrameLayout>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/persistentBottomSheet"
app:behavior_peekHeight="@dimen/bottom_sheet_peek_height"
app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
    tools:context="com.yoursite.yourapp.YourActivity">

<!-- Whatever you want on the bottom sheet. -->

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#324">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtSearch"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1" />


        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```